# problem while using RouteOnAttribute (cannot read json attribute and always sends flow to unmatch)

Tags: apache-nifi

while using `RouteOnAttribute` nifi processor , i have input of `json` data

`[{"dev":"xyz","detail":"abc"}]` which i got from convertRecord processor

Routing Strategy :Route to Property name

ifmatch: `${dev:equals( "xyz" )}`

I tried  `${dev:matches( "xyz")}` in both single quotes and double quotes still am not getting flowfile redirecting towards "ifmatch" . its redirecting to unmatched

is there anyway to resolve this  i tried many other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flowfile *content* is different from *attributes*. Content is arbitrary -- could be empty, text, KB of XML, GB of video or binary. Each flowfile also has *attributes* which are key/value pairs of `String`s kept in memory.

If you want to route on this piece of data, you have multiple options:

1. Use `RouteOnText` or `RouteOnContent` to use the actual flowfile content directly.
2. Extract it to an attribute using `EvaluateJsonPath` and then route on that attribute.

The [Apache NiFi User Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#terminology) and [In-Depth](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html#intro) provide more information around this distinction.

Comment: Am using EvaluateJsonPath and below is my configuration 

Destination:flowfile-attribute
Return Type: auto-detect
Path Not Found Behavior: warn
Null Value Representation :empty string
Device : $.dev

i am getting Device as empty string  when i check in flowfile attributes

is their any particular reason

Comment: Your content is an array of JSON objects, not a single one, so you'll need something like `$[0].dev` to extract the `dev` key/value pair from the first (zero-indexed) element of the array.